# how am I supposed to call the function?

Tags: python

I wrote a program which tells you knight's movement (chess).
For example if I wanted to know all possible moves, I'd input:

`possibilites("F4")` and I'd get `['D3', 'D5', 'E2', 'E6', 'G2', 'G6', 'H3', 'H5']` as a result, ok I did that, next, I had to write a function in which you input two fields and if those fields are legal, you'd get True and if they're not you'd get False(I had to use the previous function).
For example:

```
legal("F4","D3")
>>>True
```

code:

```
def legal(field1,field2):
  c=possibilities(field1)
  if field1 and field2 in a:
     return True

  return False
```

I'm having a problem with the following function which I have to write:
I have to put in path of the knight and my function has to tell me if it's legal path, I'm obliged to use the previous function.

for example:

```
>>> legal_way(["F3", "E1", "G2", "H4", "F5"])
True
>>> legal_way(["F3", "E1", "G3", "H5"])
False
>>> legal_way(["B4"])
True
```

I know I have to loop through the list and put first and second item on it in `legal(field1,field2)` and if it's false, everything is false, but if it's true I have to continue to the end, and this has to work also if I have only one field.
I'm stuck, what to do?

```
def legal_way(way): 
   a=len(way) 
   for i in range(0,a-2):
      if a==1:
         return true
      else:
         if legal(way[i],way[i+1]): 
            return True 
         return False
```

and I get True or index out of range

Comment: You have ``a``, but that variable doesn't exist. Is it meant to be ``c``?

Comment: I'm thinking his `legal` method was typed from memory for this question, as in the above implementation it both (1) does not compile and (2) will always return `False`, as the `possibilities()` will never contain both `field1` and `field2`

Comment: yes a is supposed to be c and function legal is working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I think an appropriate solution to the `legal_way` method would be to:

1. Determine the length `len`, of the array parameter `param` containing the path items.
2. Iterate from `0` to `len - 2`, and at each iteration, check to see if the `legal` method returns `True` for (`param[i]`, `param[i+1]`)

*You'll have to include special conditions for when the length of `param` is `0` or `1`*

It should be as easy as that - good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't get it:(

Comment: Which part is causing you trouble? Have you used `for` loops before? If not, I would recommend Googling "python for loop" and understanding how they work and how they might help in this situation.

Comment: Okay! Edit your original question, and add the code you have now for `legal_way`. Without seeing your code, or knowing specifically what isn't working, we can't be much help.

Comment: Try stepping through your current `legal_way` code with a pen and pencil. What happens the first time `legal_way` calls the `legal` method, and it returns? Does it ever get a chance to try the next pair?